# Best way to demo a Spring batch application on cloud foundry

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, cloud-foundry

I have a Spring batch application deployed on Cloud foundry. I used to run this via Rest Controller or Spring boot main method using jobLauncher.  This batch job also requires a CSV file in one of its steps (first step) which by default is read from class path (new ClassPathResource("input.csv")).  However, now for demo purpose I would like to send this using Swagger ui via the Rest Controller of Spring to batch job i.e. CSV file -> Swagger Ui -> Rest Controller -> Spring batch. Any suggestions on how to achieve this ?

Comment: What you're proposing sounds perfectly reasonable.  Not sure what your question is though.  Is there some specific problem you're having as you try to code this together?  Are you looking for examples on how to do something?  The more specific you can be in your request, the easier it will be for people to help.

Comment: Why not launch via Spring Cloud Data Flow?

Comment: Hi @MichaelMinella and Daniel Mikusa, Thank you for your inputs. Sorry for not being very specific. By Cloud foundry,  I meant SAP Cloud foundry. I would've  loved to use Spring Cloud Data Flow ( I have yet to try it). But, I doubt if SAP already has enabled its version of Cloud data flow. I will definitely check that out. Meanwhile, to resolve this I have used persistence (SAP HANA) to store the CSV file from inside REST Controller. Now when the job executes, I fetch the CSV from the DB and process it. This works fine for now. Thank you Michael for the Spring batch tutorials and the framework

Comment: @DanielMikusa, The challenge I had was not being able to pass CSV file from REST controller to batch job. Since, in my case the Rest controller triggers the batch job passing the job parameters, ideally I would have preferred passing the CSV file as one of the parameters or at least via some means. As I mentioned in the earlier comment, currently I have used DB to save the CSV(forced to do it due to the limitation mentioned, but not required by application) from Rest controller and again fetch the same inside the Job execution. Hope this approach is fine ?

Comment: @SantoshKashyap - The simplest solution would be for the controller to write the file to a temp directory and pass the temp file name to the batch job.  Writing temporary files is OK as they'll survive until the next app restart.  The problem you'd have to watch out for is if the app crashes/restarts.  In that case, you'd lose the file so if your batch job tries to restart when the app comes back up the data would be gone.

Comment: If you're using multiple applications (one for web, one for batch, or just want the possibility to do this later), you'd need to use a database or message queue to send the information across, since the filesystem is unique for each app.  I don't see anything wrong with doing it this way.

Comment: I suppose you could also use S3 or something like that.  Where the web app takes the CSV file, pushes it to S3 for storage, then passes the URL to your batch job which fetches it.  If you've got really large files, this could be a good option.

Comment: hi @DanielMikusa, Thank you the detailed write-up. This answers my question. I think for now storing the file in tmp directory seems viable for my scenario and may be enhance this in future.